# Get Spark session on executor

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

After deploying a spark structure streaming application, how can I obtain a spark session on the executor for deploying another job with the same session and same configuration settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get spark session on to executor if you are running spark in cluster mode as spark session object cannot be serialised thus cannot send it to executor. Also, it is against spark design principles to do so.

I may be able to help you with this if you can tell me the problem statement.

Comment: what if i want reuse SparkSession(started on yarn) in a `dataframe.foreachPartition` function

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can get spark session on the executor doesn't matter which mode you are running it in but not really worth the effort.Spark session is an object of various internal spark settings along with other user defined settings we provide on startup.

The only reason those configuration settings are not available in executor is because most of them are marked as **transient** which means those objects will be sent as null as it does not make logical sense to send them to the executors, in the same way it does not make sense to send database connection objects from one node to another.

One of the cumbersome ways to do this would be to get all configuration settings from your spark session in your driver, set in some custom object marked as serializable and send it to the executor. Also your executor environment should be same as driver in terms of all spark jars/directories and other spark properties such as **SPARK_HOME** etc which can be hectic if you run and realize every time you are missing something. It will be a different spark session object but with all the same settings.

The better option would be to run another spark application with the same settings you provide for your other application as one spark session is associated for one spark application.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. I also had similar requirement then I have to create two separate main class and one spark launcher class in that I was doing sparksession.conf.set(main class name ) based on which class i wanted to run. If I want to run both then I was using thread.sleep()  to complete first before launching another. I also used sparkListener code to get status whether it has completed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this is a late response. Just thought this might be useful.
So, you can use something like the below code snippet in you spark structured streaming application:

for spark versions <= 3.2.1

```
spark_session_for_this_micro_batch = microBatchOutputDF._jdf.sparkSession()
```

For spark versions >= 3.3.1:

```
spark_session_for_this_micro_batch = microBatchOutputDF.sparkSession
```

Your function can use this spark session to create dataframe there.
You can refer this [medium post](https://canadiandataguy.medium.com/using-spark-streaming-to-merge-upsert-data-into-a-delta-lake-6d34c827a892)
[pyspark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sparkSession.html?highlight=dataframe.sparksession#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sparkSession)